# Finding the limit of a multivariable function with cosines in it

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

In this exercise, I have to show that the limit either exists or does not and justify the answer. Here's the limit:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{\{x,y\}\to\{0,0\}}\frac{x^4y^3\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)}{x^2+y^2}$$

I tried using polar coordinates but it still did not work for me. My question is about finding the limit of this multivariable function. I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: The limit is zero , you use the fact that the cosine is inferior to 1 and THEN use polar coordinates

Comment: The fraction $\frac{\cos(\cdots)}{x^2+y^2}$ is less (in magnitude) than 1. So if you call the expression from the limit $f(x,y)$, you have $-|x^4y^3| < f(x,y) < |x^4y^3|$. Then you can use the squeeze theorem.